# Can I create a install an OS on a USB without rebooting?

Tags: usb, installation

I want to install Arch Linux on a USB (not just flash an ISO), just like how one would install to a normal drive. However, I wanna do it while still using my main OS normally, without rebooting. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The normal way to do this is to run a Virtual Machine. That is what I do.

Comment: You want to install it without rebooting or you want to run it without rebooting? First might be possible, second needs a VM.

Comment: @Tetsujin install without reboot

Answer (score 0):

I did this using 2 USB one to boot Live Session and the second to install the system on. Try it using vm, but at the end only working solution was this. Performance will be usable if you use m.2 nvme with usb 3 case.